# Can googlemock mock method calls from within other method calls of the same class?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Is it possible to mock method calls from within other method calls of the same class?  I am new to C++ (primarily a C developer) and very new to googlemock and Google Test so forgive me if this is answered elsewhere and I didn't understand the answer!  Below is a simple example that should explain what I want to do.  Using the example below, I want to mock `ReturnInput`, while testing `ReturnInputPlus1`.

```
using ::testing::Invoke;
using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::Return;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : x(1) {}
    virtual ~MyClass() {}

    int ReturnInput(int x) { return x; }
    int ReturnInputPlus1(int x) { return ReturnInput(x) + 1; }
};

class MockMyClass : public MyClass
{
public:
    MockMyClass()
    {
        ON_CALL(*this, ReturnInput(_)).WillByDefault(Invoke(&real, &MyClass::ReturnInput));
        ON_CALL(*this, ReturnInputPlus1(_)).WillByDefault(Invoke(&real, &MyClass::ReturnInputPlus1));
    }
    virtual ~MockMyClass() {}

    MOCK_METHOD1(ReturnInput, int(int y));
    MOCK_METHOD1(ReturnInputPlus1, int(int));

private:
    MyClass real;
};

TEST(MyClassTest, mockUseClassMethod)
{
    MockMyClass mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, ReturnInput(_))
        .WillOnce(Return(2));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, ReturnInputPlus1(_))
        .Times(1);

    EXPECT_EQ(3, mock.ReturnInputPlus1(1));
}
```

When I run the above test, I would expect all the tests to succeed.  Instead I get the following output:

```
1>[ RUN      ] MyClassTest.mockUseClassMethod
1>.\MyClassTest.cpp(15): error: Value of: mock.ReturnInputPlus1(1)
1>  Actual: 2
1>Expected: 3
1>.\DllInfoTest.cpp(10): error: Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, ReturnInput(_))...
1>         Expected: to be called once
1>           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `MockMyClass::ReturnInputPlus1(1)` calls `MyClass::ReturnInputPlus1(1)` on `real` by default, which calls `MyClass::ReturnInput(2)`. The object that `ReturnInputPlus1()` is running on is not `mock`, it's `mock.real`, and when it calls `ReturnInput()` it calls the original version of the function. What you want to do is create a MockMyClass that has a mock override of `ReturnInput()` but doesn't mock out `ReturnInputPlus1()` at all -- you don't want to have both a mock version of your class and a real version that it sometimes delegates to.